# Android app not running on emulator

Tags: android

i wanted to use android for developing mobile app.i have installed eclipse an java jdk and jre according to the steps given on android.developer site but i cant see the hello world application on emulator.I hav tried ample of ways but its not wrkin.I have vista home 32 bit
Please help me.

Comment: Do you get any feedback from the emulator? Is it starting at all? Do you get an error message?

Comment: yes i saw in error log cat it says files not loaded properly of project...and the error is dat "an exception for stack trace not available" mnot abe to understand dis

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn how to Debug in Eclipse and how to use the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618172953/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) tools.

In order to get more details about an exception/force close you need to look for a view in Eclipse called [Logcat](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324231958/http://developer.android.com:80/intl/de/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html)(you will find in the [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825232742/http://www.brighthub.com:80/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx) perspective) there you will find a detailed traceback when/what and on what line is the issue.

For this you should read a complete article about [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [droidnova.com](http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-3.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have done following

- Have u installed Android SDK?
- adb.exe path set in the eclipse IDE. Also add it to PATH variable.

Comment: i hav installed sdk but d setup doesnt run properly it was installed initially bt later d setup.exe window is visible just for few sec an den vaishes as i tried to reinstall it.
but d emulator is running properly frm eclipse an d adt is also imported properly..
i hav added d path bt it isnt wrkin stil.. :-(

Comment: as you have also seen logcat, the only thing I can suggest is to clean everything and start again.